# Decomposing a uniform discrete random variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance, uniform-distribution

**Question**: I want to decompose a uniform random variable $X\sim\text{Uniform}\{0,q\}$, for some fixed constant $q$, such that it can be rewritten in terms of another random variable $\widetilde{X}$ whose mean is zero and variance is $1/n$. How can I do this? Thanks.

**My attempt:** I couldn't figure out how to do this for the discrete uniform random variable, but I managed to figure out how to do this for a Bernoulli random variable $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(\alpha)$, for some fixed $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Hopefully this gives you a flavor of what I am looking for. I have
$$
X=\alpha+\sqrt{n\alpha(1-\alpha)}\widetilde{X},
$$
where $\mathbb{E}[\widetilde{X}]=0$ and $\text{Var}[\widetilde{X}]=1/n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. It is
$$
X=\frac{q}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{n[(q+1)^2-1]}{12}}\times\widetilde{X}.
$$

Comment: Are you sure $Var(X)$ in the expression above computes to $q^2/12$?

Comment: How about $X = q/2 + q \sqrt{{n \over 12}} \tilde X$?